# How to override custom Jackson deserializer in child project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

In our company library (say `lib-a`) we have an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    ...
}
```

and its default implementation:

```
public enum DefaultMyImpl implements MyInterface {
    ...
}
```

a serializer for it:

```
public class DefaultMyInterfaceSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyInterface> {
    @Override
    public MyInterface deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return parser.readValuesAs(DefaultMyImpl.class).next();
    }
}
```

and for Jackson we have:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer defaultObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
    return builder -> builder
            .deserializerByType(MyInterface.class, new DefaultMyInterfaceSerializer());
}
```

and in a child project that has a dependency on `lib-a`, we might have another implementation:

```
public enum ChildMyImpl implements MyInterface {
    ...
}
```

and a serializer for it:

```
public class ChildMyInterfaceSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyInterface> {
    @Override
    public MyInterface deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return parser.readValuesAs(ChildMyImpl.class).next();
    }
}
```

and it's related Jackson configuration:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer childObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
    return builder -> builder
            .deserializerByType(MyInterface.class, new ChildMyInterfaceDeserializer());
}
```

However, I don't seem to be able to override `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` deserializer for `MyInterface`. I'm getting this Http 400 error on deserialization:

```
Bad Request: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.company.library.domain.DefaultMyImpl` from String "SOME_STRING": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [DEFAUL_ENUM_VAL]
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 30]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.company.library.domain.DefaultMyImpl` from String "SOME_STRING": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [DEFAUL_ENUM_VAL]
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 30] (through reference chain: com.company.library.domain.MyInterface["..."])
```

Thinking it is because the customizer in the library overrides the child project's I've tried putting:

```
@DependsOn(value = "defaultObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer")
```

or

```
@Order(value = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

on top of child customizer `@Bean` to no avail. How do I order them in the way that child project overrides the one in the dependency (`lib-a`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to implement `BeanPostProcessor` and override it there:

```
@Configuration
public class FinalJacksonConfiguration implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
            final Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = (Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) bean;
            builder.serializerByType(MyInterface.class, new ChildMyInterfaceDeserializer());
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```